# spring batch integration configuration with azure service bus

Tags: spring, spring-batch, azureservicebus

I am trying to configure inbound and outbound adaptors as provided in the spring batch remote partitioning samples for Manager and worker beans. Having difficulty since they are configured in context of AMQPConnectionFactory.
However when I follow spring integration samples, there is no class which can provide Connection Factory. Help appreciated.

Below is sample code:-

```
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.integration.core.DefaultMessageHandler;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.integration.core.api.CheckpointConfig;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.integration.core.api.CheckpointMode;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.integration.servicebus.inbound.ServiceBusQueueInboundChannelAdapter;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.integration.servicebus.queue.ServiceBusQueueOperation;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.RemotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallback;

@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class ManagerConfiguration {

    private static final int GRID_SIZE = 3;

    private static final String REQUEST_QUEUE_NAME = "digital.intg.batch.cm.request";
    private static final String REPLY_QUEUE_NAME = "digital.intg.batch.cm.reply";
    private static final String MANAGER_INPUT_CHANNEL = "manager.input";
    private static final String MANGER_OUTPUT_CHANNEL = "manager.output";

    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(ManagerConfiguration.class);
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final RemotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory managerStepBuilderFactory;

    public ManagerConfiguration(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
            RemotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory managerStepBuilderFactory
    ) {

        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.managerStepBuilderFactory = managerStepBuilderFactory;
    }

    /*
     * Configure outbound flow (requests going to workers)
     */
    @Bean( name = MANGER_OUTPUT_CHANNEL )
    public DirectChannel managerRequests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    /*
     * Configure inbound flow (replies coming from workers)
     */
    @Bean( name = MANAGER_INPUT_CHANNEL )
    public DirectChannel managerReplies() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceBusQueueInboundChannelAdapter managerQueueMessageChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier( MANAGER_INPUT_CHANNEL ) MessageChannel inputChannel, ServiceBusQueueOperation queueOperation) {
        queueOperation.setCheckpointConfig(CheckpointConfig.builder().checkpointMode(CheckpointMode.MANUAL).build());
        ServiceBusQueueInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new ServiceBusQueueInboundChannelAdapter(REPLY_QUEUE_NAME,
                queueOperation);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator( inputChannel = MANGER_OUTPUT_CHANNEL )
    public MessageHandler managerQueueMessageSender(ServiceBusQueueOperation queueOperation) {
        DefaultMessageHandler handler = new DefaultMessageHandler(REQUEST_QUEUE_NAME, queueOperation);
        handler.setSendCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                LOGGER.info("Manager Request Message was sent successfully.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                LOGGER.info("There was an error sending request message to worker.");
            }
        });

        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow managerOutboundFlow(MessageHandler managerQueueMessageSender) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(managerRequests())
                .handle(managerQueueMessageSender)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow managerInboundFlow(ServiceBusQueueInboundChannelAdapter managerQueueMessageChannelAdapter) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(managerQueueMessageChannelAdapter)
                .channel(managerReplies())
                .get();
    }

    /*
     * Configure the manager step
     */
    @Bean
    public Step managerStep() {
        return this.managerStepBuilderFactory.get("managerStep")
                .partitioner("workerStep", new BasicPartitioner())
                .gridSize(GRID_SIZE)
                .outputChannel(managerRequests())
                .inputChannel(managerReplies())
                //.aggregator()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job remotePartitioningJob() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("remotePartitioningJob")
                .start(managerStep())
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for what you have tried?

Comment: edited to provide code snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The sample uses ActiveMQ because it is easily embeddable in a JVM for our tests and samples. But you can use any other broker that you want.

> ?? what should I inject here?

You should inject any dependency required by the `queueMessageChannelAdapter` handler:

```
.handle(queueMessageChannelAdapter)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahmound Ben Hassine, may be I was not very clear. I do see configuration for 'ServiceBusQueueInboundChannelAdapter' but I could not find a class something like "ServiceBusQueueOutboundChannelAdaptor" which I can configure for OUTPUT_CHANNEL ?

Comment: By `ServiceBusQueueInboundChannelAdapter` are you referring to https://github.com/microsoft/spring-cloud-azure/blob/master/spring-integration-azure/spring-integration-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/spring/integration/servicebus/inbound/ServiceBusQueueInboundChannelAdapter.java?

Comment: I started following example from

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/spring-cloud-azure/blob/master/spring-cloud-azure-samples/servicebus-integration-sample/src/main/java/com/example which has configuration of sending and receiving messsages from a azure queue. Then I started looking into remote partitioning example of configuring Aggregated Manager and Worker configuration. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/remotepartitioning/aggregating.how to add adaptors as required for communicating stepExecutionContexts between Manager/ Workers ?

Comment: The second link in your last comment is dead. That said, I'm not familiar with this azure project. What you need to do is to make sure your Spring Integration adapter correctly sends messages from the `requests` channel to the azure queue.

Comment: here is the fixed link. Not sure I think it got trimmed or something. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/remotepartitioning/aggregating. One additional question regarding aggregator is that previously with xml configuration we used to also inject aggregator bean as below.     <int:aggregator ref="genericEtlPartitionHandler" input-channel="inboundStaging" output-channel="outboundReplies"/> . I don't see that how where aggregation of of the replies from all remote workers is getting handled ?

Comment: I further updated the code as above. However getting below error. nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect type specified for header 'replyChannel'. Expected [class java.lang.String] but actual type is [class org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel]